# how to save id but display value in rails-jquery-autocomplete

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, autocomplete

I am using rails3.2 with ruby1.9.3. I am implementing jquery autocomplete which is working fine. I have following result with firebug console.

```
[{"id":2,"label":"shiv  raj","value":"shiv  raj"},{"id":14,"label":"shiv badu","value":"shiv badu"}]
```

Autocomplete is displaying user name value according to need. How to extract id of selected value so that i can save id easily?

In View file:

```
<%= f.autocomplete_field :owner_id, autocomplete_user_full_name_groups_path(:account_id=>current_user.account_id), :class=>"form-control", :placeholder=>"Owner Name", :id_element=>"#owner_id" %>
```

In Controller:

```
autocomplete :user, :full_name
```

Waiting for your solution.

Comment: I have solved this task by using ajax search and passing variable with  jquery.